# How to deploy a Bokeh application on the internet

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a bokeh application which I developed locally. I used the bokeh client (command bokeh serve --show main.py) to start it to view my results. However, now I would like to push the application to my server so that anyone who enters my domain can see and use my application. I read that the bokeh server should be capable to accomplish this. But the documentation does not explain to me how I can do this. I have loaded my main.py and the data set onto the server already. How can I tell the server to start the application whenever a client connects to him?